# Attribute Qt::AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL must be set before QCoreApplication is created

Tags: python, spyder, miniconda

So my environment is:

- Windows 10, up to date as of 2019-11-08
- Installed Python 3.6, Spyder 4 via miniconda
- run miniconda shell
- activate virtualenv
- run Spyder

I get the following (in the shell):

```
(base) C:\Users\bbate>activate keras-gpu  
(keras-gpu) C:\Users\bbate>spyder  
Attribute Qt::AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL must be set before QCoreApplication is created.  
[968:13624:1108/111945.157:ERROR:permission_manager_qt.cpp(82)] NOT IMPLEMENTEDUnsupported permission type: 13
```

However, Spyder4 launches and works, but every now and it it just hangs, and I've seen other notes suggesting it has something to do with the qt dll but I do not know how to fix this

I've seen various posts but nothing addressing this error

BTW, this is a "clean" install; the drive had just been rebuilt and everything being installed fresh, so there isn't much clutter around, other versions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This problem is going to be fixed in Spyder **4.1.0**, to be released later in March 2020.

Comment: I have experienced almost the same issue, however, in my case I am on macOS Catalina 10.15.3 with python=3.8. Also, running from a env results in a total crash, from the base I just get the warning after which spyder works.

Comment: Python 3.8 is still not very well supported. Please use 3.7 for a couple more months.