# Failed to start spyder kernel after setting Python interpreter to new environment

Tags: anaconda, kernel, conda, spyder, environment

I made a new environment where I installed geopandas, xarray, and regionmask. When I tried to switch environment using the modular approach (by installing spyder-kernels in the new environment and indicating the new path to the environment in the Python interpreter, as indicated here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder#the-modular-approach), an error persists while starting the kernel:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Justin\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Users\Justin\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\Justin\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 11, in 
start.main()
File "C:\Users\Justin\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 288, in main
import_spydercustomize()
File "C:\Users\Justin\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 39, in import_spydercustomize
import spydercustomize
File "C:\Users\Justin\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 27, in 
from spyder_kernels.comms.frontendcomm import CommError, frontend_request
File "C:\Users\Justin\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 17, in 
from jupyter_client.localinterfaces import localhost
File "C:\Users\Justin\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in 
from .connect import *
File "C:\Users\Justin\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 21, in 
import zmq
File "C:\Users\Justin\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site‑packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in 
from zmq import backend
File "C:\Users\Justin\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in 
reraise(*exc_info)
File "C:\Users\Justin\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site‑packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\Justin\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)
File "C:\Users\Justin\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
File "C:\Users\Justin\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: The specified module could not be found.
```

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

(Spyder maintainer here) This problem was fixed in this [pull request](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/pull/11327), which is going to be part of Spyder **4.1.0**, to be released later in March 2020.

Comment: @SamuelLiew, I consider my previous answer was appropriate, but I give more details in this one to not make a repeated one. I've only answered with the same text once before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60535220/438386). The problem is I'm very busy to look around our [hundred issues and PRs](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues?q=label%3Av4.1.0+is%3Aclosed+sort%3Aupdated-desc) for the specifics of each case, when I know for sure that the problem was fixed in a certain version and few users care about those details. So I'd appreciate some courtesy next time.

Comment: apologies, I am very new to all of this hence this may come as a noob question. For me to continue, should I downgrade my spyder version? Thanks !

Comment: @Justin, no worries, your question was appropriate and I think my previous answer was too. My rant was with a StackOverflow moderator, not with you. And please don't downgrade, just wait until the end of this week and try to update Spyder. Our 4.1.0 version should be available by then.